# How to organize server's CPU like TC(Traffic control) in linux

Tags: linux

I have a running server which has 100 users. When users connect to server and run their programs cpu hits high values after a while. How can i organize my server's cpu like organizing network with tc (traffic control) in linux. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you're running a modern kernel, you can limit resource access with `cgroups`.

- http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/cgroups.txt

Answer (score 0):

[**man ulimit**](http://ss64.com/bash/ulimit.html) for how to do this inside a shell, somewhat.

Of course, you don't specify what "connect to server and run programs" actually entails.